# Hypersurfaces in Grassmannians

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying Chow forms from the book *Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants* of  Andrei Zelevinsky and Izrail' Moiseevič Gel'fand. In order to introduce Chow forms the authors prove this proposition.

[image]
[image]

To be honest there is something I don't understand.

(1) When the authors define the degree of a surface in $G(k,n)$ they use the word *generic pencil*? What does this term mean?

(2) I know that the sheaf $\mathcal{O}(d)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the sheaf defined as 
$$\mathcal{O}(d)(U):=\lbrace f\colon p^{-1}(U)\longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \textit{ holomorphic and s.t. } f(tz)=t^df(z), \: \forall t\in\mathbb{C} \rbrace.$$

where $p$ is the usual projection $p\colon \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus{0}\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^N$.

How is defined the restriction of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ to $G(k,n)$? I would appreciate a lot if someone could explain me the proof of the equality $d=d'$ in the proposition below.

Thanks in advance.

- Proposition $1.6$

[image]

Comment: 1) "Pencil" just means a family of objects indexed by a $\Bbb P^1$. You should think of this as some sort of analogy with $\Bbb P^1$ being a line and pencils drawing lines.

2) For a projective variety with a chosen inclusion $i: X\hookrightarrow \Bbb P^n$, $\mathcal{O}_X(d)=i^*\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(d)$ is just pullback of $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n}(d)$ along the inclusion $i$.

3) What specifically are you having a problem with in the proof? Is the general strategy okay? Is there one particular point that's hard?

Comment: I don't understand in what way the result $d=d'$ follows by the fact that $\mathcal{O}_{G(k,n)}(l)\simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(l)$.

Comment: Edit: I have understood why the isomorphism above proves the proposition, it follows by the fact that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)(\mathbb{P}^n)$ consists only of the homogeneous polynomial havig degree $d$, right? Now I have only some troubles to understand how they check $\mathcal{O}_{G(k,n)}(1)_{|P_{NM}}\simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$.